# Change a Javascript variable value from code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, progress-bar

I have this javascript code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var progValue1 = 100;
    var progValue2 = 30; 
    $("#progressbar").progressbar({ value: progValue1});
    $("#progressbar2").progressbar({ value: progValue2 });
});
</script>
```

I would like to change the values of the two variables (`progValue1` and `progValue2`) from the code behind when a button is clicked .....

This is the code for the button

```
<asp:Button ID="btnConfirm" CssClass="button" SkinID="Common" runat="server" Text=  "Confirm" OnClick="btnConfirm_Click" />
```

How can I change those values from the C# code for the `btnConfirm` method?

Comment: see this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3655766/assign-value-to-javascript-variable-in-c-sharp-codebehind

Comment: @PranayRana i just marked the answer that worked for me... is that what you wanted to know?

Comment: @WaqarJanjua saw that post... it was helpful.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add two properties, i.e.

```
private int _progValue1 = 100;
private int _progValue2 = 30;

protected int ProgValue1 { get { return this._progValue1; }}
protected int ProgValue2 { get { return this._progValue2; }}
```

Modify your JS:

```
<script>   
  $(document).ready(function() {   
    var progValue1 = <%=ProgValue1%>;   
    var progValue2 = <%=ProgValue2%>;    
    $("#progressbar").progressbar({ value: progValue1});   
    $("#progressbar2").progressbar({ value: progValue2 });   
  });   
</script>
```

Then set the values in your OnClick event handler:

```
this._progValue1 = 40;
this._progValue2 = 20;
```

Comment: i changed this a bit to "set" otherwise it was giving me a error.... 
    public int ProgValue1 { get { return this._progValue1; } set { _progValue1 = value; } }
    public int ProgValue2 { get { return this._progValue2; } set { _progValue2 = value; } }

Comment: @riznomdemha - sorry about that, I corrected my code but you can use setters as well.  Same difference.

Answer (score 1):

What I assume from your query that you want to change the value of Javascript variable from code behind means, you want to send value from code behind to javascript. You can use ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock to achieve this. To more elobrate, see the code below:

JS

```
function ChangeValue(value1)
{
   yourvariable = value1;
}
```

Code Behind

```
private void SomeMethod()
{
   string newvalue = "test value"; //need to pass this to JS var
   ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this,typeof(Page),"key","ChangeValue("+ newvalue +");",true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function () {
        var progValue1 = parseInt('<%=ProgValue1%>');
        $("#progressbar").progressbar({ value: progValue1 });
    });


private int _progValue1 = 1;

    protected int ProgValue1
    {
        get
        {
            return _progValue1;
        }
    }
```